# My programming language's lexer will not process input

Tags: javascript, interpreter, lexer

I am writing a **very** simple programming language in Javascript. It has a lexer of only one word. When the word is called, the lexer is supposed to put the contents of an input box into an alert box. Instead, nothing happens. There is no error in the console, nothing. I am writing the lexer in a seperate file to the interpreter. Here is my code.
Lexer:

```
function ScratchLexer(text) {
  var words = text.split(/\s+/);
  var next = 0;
  this.nextWord = function () {
    if (next >= words.length) return null;
    return words[next++];
  };
}

function Scratch() {
  var dictionary = {};

  this.addWords = function (new_dict) {
    for (var word in new_dict)
      dictionary[word.toUpperCase()] = new_dict[word];
  };

  this.run = function (text) {
    var lexer = new ScratchLexer(text);
    var word;

    while (word = lexer.nextWord()) {
      word = word.toUpperCase();
      num_val = parseFloat(word);
      if (dictionary[word]) {
        dictionary[word](this);
      } else if (!isNaN(num_val)) {
        this.stack.push(num_val);
      } else {
        throw "Unknown word";
      }
    }
  };
}

var PrintingWords = {
  "ALERT": function (terp) {
    var tos = terp.document.getElementById("Text").value.pop(); alert(tos);
  }
}
```

Interpreter:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scratch-lang.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var terp = new Scratch();

 terp.addWords(PrintingWords);
 terp.addWords(MathWords);

  var alertwords = document.getElementById("TextAlert");
 </script>

 <style type="text/css">
  body { Margin: 2em 5em; Line-height: 2em; Font-family: serif; }
  body { Background-color: #ffffff; Color: #000000; }
  #TextAlert { Width: 32em; }
  #Text { Width: 32em; }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <br />
 <input id="TextAlert" value = ""/><input id = 'run' type = 'button' value = 
 'Run' />
 <br />
 <input id="Text" value = ""/>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to recreate a runnable example here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Where are PrintingWords and Mathwords assigned? Do you want the function called when the run button is pressed? You have not assigned an event handler for pressing the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your `<input id="TextAlert" value = ""/><input id = 'run' type = 'button' value ='Run' />` button hooked up to the lexer code in any way? I can't see how your lexical analysis is being initiated. You probably need to hook the `run` function up to the interface properly.

Some code like this will help you get started.

```
function handleRunClick(e) {
    var value = document.getElementById("TextAlert").value;
    terp.run(value);
}

<input id="TextAlert" value =""/><input id="run" type="button" onClick="handleRunClick" />
```

Comment: How do I do that?